IIS log double entries with 401 and then 200
net 8 app hosting on Windows 2016 IIS v10.  It is an intranet app and I ONLY have the Windows authentication turned ON.  Running ok but when I look at the IIS logs there are A LOT of 401 entries just before 200 for the same POST:
Examples (10.1.2.3 is the web server fake ip and 10.4.5.6 is my workstation fake ip):
2024-11-28 01:07:18 10.1.2.3 POST /status/v1/dbcheck - 44337 - 10.4.5.6 Mozilla......https://myweb.blah.au 401 2 5 15
2024-11-28 01:07:18 10.1.2.3 POST /status/v1/dbcheck - 44337 - mydomain\myusername 10.4.5.6 Mozilla......https://myweb.blah.au 200 0 0 187
It looks like to me somehow the browser send a POST request with only my ip address - i.e. without my domain+username first, got 401, and then send it again with my domain+username and ip address and get thru.
How does it happen and how to resolve this problem?
Thanks.

That’s how challenge based authentication methods work. Use search engines to learn more.

hi @LexLi, are you saying it is not a problem?
